# How can I add multiple images along with other input fields in vue js html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vue-component

My html code is

I also need to add sez which is in array format and also i need to add multiple images, need to provide add image and when clicking on it, need to add images as needed by the client

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" v-on:submit.prevent="handleSubmit($event);">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label">Alias</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="alias">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label">Sex</label>
        <select class="form-control" v-model="sex" id="level">
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" v-for="(book, index) in sez" :key="index">


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label">Date </label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="book.date">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label"> Details</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" book.details>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a @click="addNewRow">Add</a>

  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="button success expand radius">
          <span id="save_image_titlebar_logo_live">Signature</span>
          <label class="custom-file-upload"><input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*"  />
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="button success expand radius">
          <span id="save_image_titlebar_logo_live">Recent Photograph</span>
          <label class="custom-file-upload">
        <input type="file" name="sign"/>
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My vue js code is

```
addForm = new Vue({
  el: "#addForm",
  data: {
    name: '',
    alias: '',
    sex: '',
    sez: [{
      date: null,
      details: null,

    }, ],
    photo: '',
    sign: '',
  },
  methods: {
    addNewRow: function() {
      this.seziure.push({
        date: null,
        details: null,
      });
    },

    handleSubmit: function(e) {
      var vm = this;
      data = {};
      data['sez'] = this.sez;
      data['name'] = this.name;
      data['alias'] = this.alias;
      data['sex'] = this.sex;
      //how to add images
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/save/',
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(e) {
          if (e.status) {
            vm.response = e;
            alert("success")

          } else {
            vm.response = e;
            console.log(vm.response);
            alert("Registration Failed")
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    },
  },
});
```

This is my code. I have no idea about how to add images in this case.

Can anyone please help me pass this data.

How to pass this data along with images to the backend?

I don't want to use base64 encoding. I need to just pass this image in this ajax post request along with other data

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041171/best-approach-for-file-upload-with-vue?rq=1) has a couple of options for file uploading with Vue.  Also, a google search of "vue upload file" returned a lot of results that should help you out.

Comment: Are you just looking for file upload, I used formData but I have a doubt since you have an array .. otherwise you can use formdata I think .. If you get this answer, it will be a help for me too. Just upload when you receive the same

Comment: What do you have in the backend?

Comment: node js sir.. i need to just pass the data from front end

Comment: this video could be useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=327haEC7iFA&t=899s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure where would you like the extra images to appear, but I added them after this column:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="button success expand radius">
    <span id="save_image_titlebar_logo_live">Recent Photograph</span>
    <label class="custom-file-upload">
  <input type="file" name="sign"/>
  </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the column I added — "add images": *(You can try this feature [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjQxQX), with the updates)*

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="list-group" :if="images.length">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(f, index) in images" :key="index">
      <button class="close" @click.prevent="removeImage(index, $event)">&times;</button>
      <div class="button success expand radius">
        <label class="custom-file-upload">
          <input type="file" class="images[]" accept="image/*" @change="previewImage(index, $event)">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div :class="'images[' + index + ']-preview image-preview'"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="btn btn-link add-image" @click.prevent="addNewImage">Add Image</button>
</div>
```

And the full Vue JS code (with `jQuery.ajax()`):

```
addForm = new Vue({
  el: "#addForm",
  data: {
    name: '',
    alias: '',
    sex: '',
    sez: [{
      date: null,
      details: null
    }],
    // I removed `photo` and `sign` because (I think) the're not necessary.
    // Add I added `images` so that we could easily add new images via Vue.
    images: [],
    maxImages: 5,
    // Selector for the "Add Image" button. Try using (or you should use) ID
    // instead; e.g. `button#add-image`. But it has to be a `button` element.
    addImage: 'button.add-image'
  },
  methods: {
    addNewRow: function() {
      // I changed to `this.sez.push` because `this.seziure` is `undefined`.
      this.sez.push({
        date: null,
        details: null
      });
    },

    addNewImage: function(e) {
      var n = this.maxImages || -1;
      if (n && this.images.length < n) {
        this.images.push('');
      }
      this.checkImages();
    },

    removeImage: function(index) {
      this.images.splice(index, 1);
      this.checkImages();
    },

    checkImages: function() {
      var n = this.maxImages || -1;
      if (n && this.images.length >= n) {
        $(this.addImage, this.el).prop('disabled', true);  // Disables the button.
      } else {
        $(this.addImage, this.el).prop('disabled', false); // Enables the button.
      }
    },

    previewImage: function(index, e) {
      var r = new FileReader(),
        f = e.target.files[0];

      r.addEventListener('load', function() {
        $('[class~="images[' + index + ']-preview"]', this.el).html(
          '<img src="' + r.result + '" class="thumbnail img-responsive">'
        );
      }, false);

      if (f) {
        r.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    },

    handleSubmit: function(e) {
      var vm = this;

      var data = new FormData(e.target);
      data.append('sez', this.sez);
      data.append('name', this.name);
      data.append('alias', this.alias);
      data.append('sex', this.sex);

      // The `data` already contain the Signature and Recent Photograph images.
      // Here we add the extra images as an array.

      $('[class~="images[]"]', this.el).each(function(i) {
        if (i > vm.maxImages - 1) {
          return; // Max images reached.
        }

        data.append('images[' + i + ']', this.files[0]);
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/save/',
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(e) {
          if (e.status) {
            vm.response = e;
            alert("success");
          } else {
            vm.response = e;
            console.log(vm.response);
            alert("Registration Failed");
          }
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
      });

      return false;
    },
  },
});
```

**Additional Notes**

I know you're using Node.js in the back-end; however, I should mention that in PHP, the `$_FILES` variable would contain all the images (so long as the fields `name` are properly set); and I suppose Node.js has a similar variable or way of getting the files.

And in the following `input`, you may have forgotten to wrap `book.details` in `v-model`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" book.details>
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="book.details"> <!-- Correct -->
```

**UPDATE**

Added feature to limit number of images allowed to be selected/uploaded, and added preview for selected image. Plus the "send images as `array`" fix.

Comment: sir, thanks a lot. One more doubt, is it possible to send images as an array(that the same way we do for sex) instead of sending as image1, image2

Comment: Try changing `<input type="file" :name="'images' + (index + 1)" accept="image/*">` to `<input type="file" name="images[]" accept="image/*">`.

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundary3Qe1EHbkhF33YbFF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[]"; filename="logo123.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundary3Qe1EHbkhF33YbFF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[]"; filename="n1opy.png"
Content-Type: image/png

Comment: this is coming sir

Comment: sir also why are you given :if="images.length"

Comment: That simply means, "if you clicked on the "Add image" button, then show the `input` there". You can remove it (i.e. the `v-if`/`:if`), if you want.

Comment: any idea regarding array of imges

Comment: Your back-end Node.js is not receiving the images as array of files? But it did receive the other images (i.e. Signature and Recent Photograph), right? What you asked is possible, though. I'll revise the code and get back later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171298/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-wanderer).

Comment: that images we are adding dynamically should be array of files ie image1, image2 and so on, you can ignore signature and recent photograph

Comment: Ok, please check the chat and try the code I provided.

Comment: Actually, change `:if="images.length"` to `v-if="images.length"`.. or just remove it if you want. Sorry about that silly mistake...

Answer (score 11):

Using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios):

#### Template

```
...
<input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" @change="setPhotoFiles($event.target.name, $event.target.files) />
...
```

#### Code

```
data () {
  return {
    ...
    photoFiles: [],
    ...
  }
},
...
methods: {
  ...
  setPhotoFiles (fieldName, fileList) {
    this.photoFiles = fileList;
  },
  ...
  handleSubmit (e) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('name', this.name);
    formData.append('alias', this.alias);
    formData.append('sex', this.sex);
    ...
    this.photoFiles.forEach((element, index, array) => {
      formData.append('photo-' + index, element);
    });

    axios.post("http://localhost:4000/save/", formData)
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        ...
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        ...
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: sir, here how will i pass sez?

Comment: @Wanderer a `FormData` object can contain multiple entries with the same name, so simply initialize the FormData passing your form element, or append `sez.data` and `sez.details` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using HTML5, try with a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object ; it will encode your file input content :

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('addForm');
formData = new FormData(myForm);
data: formData
```

Comment: can you please show how sez can be added by this code

Comment: The FormData object should include all the form's keys/values using the name property of each element.
Try to add a name to your input fields.
You can also send an array via FormData :
`for (var i = 0; i < sez.length; i++) {
    formData.append('sez[]', sez[i]);
}`

Answer (score 2):

Use below templete to show/upload the image:

```
 <div v-if="!image">
    <h2>Select an image</h2>
    <input type="file" @change="onImageUpload">
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <img :src="image" />
    <button @click="removeImage">Remove image</button>
  </div>
```

Js code:

```
data: {
    image: '',
    imageBuff: ''
},
methods: {
    onImageUpload(e) {
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length)
            return;
        this.createImage(files[0]);
    },
    createImage(file) {
        var image = new Image();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        this.imageBuff = file;

        reader.onload = (e) => {
            this.image = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    removeImage: function(e) {
        this.image = '';
    },
    handleSubmit(e) {
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('name', this.name);
        formData.append('alias', this.alias);
        formData.append('sex', this.sex);
        formData.append('image', this.imageBuff);
        ...

        // Ajax or Axios can be used
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/save/',
            data: formData,
            processData: false, // prevent jQuery from automatically transforming the data into a query string.
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                ...
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: how to add multiple images in this case. How to add sez[] in this case. Please show that too..